# How identity server authenticates a client request from behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: identityserver4

So far as I know, when a web app sends a request to the identity server, it generates a token against that request. But if the identity server is operating from behind a reverse proxy/load balancer, then, basically it will receive requests from the load balancer, and the generated token is for the load balancer. Will it work for the requestor application after receiving it from the load balancer server?

Comment: When the token is returned, it's going to come from the same place that the original request came from, whether that is the creator or the proxy.

Comment: So the response redirects to another url.

Comment: Well, a token is self-contained, right?  It isn't dependent on the route the request took to get there.